# ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND while CreateProcess

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, createprocess

Trying to run notepad by using `CreateProcess`:

```
void _tmain( int argc, TCHAR *argv[] )
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );



    // Start the child process. 
    if( !CreateProcess( "notepad.exe",   // No module name (use command line)
        NULL,        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        ) 
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
        return;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
}
```

Have error in output `2`. This means `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. Where I should start seek for a problem? Does it means it can't find `notepad.exe`?

Answer (score 4):

The `lpApplicationName` parameter must provide the full path to the application, not only its name.

More exactly:

> The string can specify the full path and file name of the module to
>   execute or it can specify a partial name. In the case of a partial
>   name, the function uses the current drive and current directory to
>   complete the specification. The function **will not use the search path**.
>   This parameter must include the file name extension; no default
>   extension is assumed.

But you're supposedly not in the current folder of `notepad.exe`. So if you want use the name only, set it in the second argument, `lpCommandLine`. And note that this string is not a constant because it is defined as an `LPTSTR` parameter this way:

> BOOL WINAPI CreateProcess(
>     _In_opt_       LPCTSTR   lpApplicationName,
>     _Inout_opt_    LPTSTR    lpCommandLine, [...]

So you have 2 variants:

```
STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

WCHAR CommandLine[] = L"notepad.exe";
if( CreateProcess( 0,   // No module name (use command line)
    CommandLine,        // Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ) 
{
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}
```

or

```
STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

if( CreateProcess( L"c:\\windows\\notepad.exe",  
    0,        // Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ) 
{
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}
```

Comment: Not everyone installs Windows to `C:\Windows` so you should not hard code the path to the Windows folder. Use `GetWindowsDirectory()` instead. Alternatively, [check the Registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121.aspx) to see if the full path to Notepad is registered.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - of course you right about path to notepad. but my goal was show usage of first and second parameter in `CreateProcessW`, this is not final code but maximal simply demo